# What is the right pattern to for numbers with negative symbol?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string of numbers separated by spaces and I need to store them in a table but for some reason negative symbol is not getting recognize.

```
cord = "-53 2 -21"
map = {}
for num in cord:gmatch("%w+") do 
    table.insert(map, num) 
end
map[1], map[2], map[3] = tonumber(map[1]), tonumber(map[2]), tonumber(map[3])
print(map[1])
print(map[2])
print(map[3])
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
53
2
21
```

I think the problem is with the pattern I'm using, what should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `"%w"` is for alphanumeric characters, which doesn't include `-`, use this pattern instead:

```
"%-?%w+"
```

or better:

```
"%-?%d+"
```

since numbers are all you need.

Answer (score 2):

`%w+` does not attempt to mach only numbers, so try `%S+` to get all "words", that is, all sequences of non-zero characters.

If you want to match only numbers, try `%-?%d+`. Note the optional minus sign in the pattern. Note also that you must escape the minus sign.

Comment: You are right, I've improved my answer according to your advice. +1.